# how to replay a fetch in chrome developer tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, fetch-api

In chrome developer tools is very useful to "replay xhr" for a xhr request (network tab).
I have started using [fetch](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch) in my code, and chrome developer tools do not allow to "replay" a fetch request, how is can it be? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Not yet implemented, apparently: https://crbug.com/573371

Comment: FWIW unless you utilize the ability to process data streams, what features of Fetch API do you need that you can't have in a promisified XHR? Also I don't like there's no way to [cancel a fetch request](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/27).

Comment: What else do you use? I could promisify xhr but since there's fetch and it's a standard in browser I thought was a good idea to use it. Before I was using angular $http and before that jquery.ajax, but now I moved to reactjs and thought fetch is a good substitute.

Comment: @wOxxOm wow, can't believe it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, seems it's not supported yet. It's a real disappointment because "replay" is just too useful to stop using it.

So I followed @wOxxOm advice and I just created a promised version of the standard xhr: https://github.com/max-favilli/helper-xhr

Comment: That's so bad, why on earth they don't let replay fetch requests

Comment: I would rather remove the fetch from window and replace it with [fetch polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) that uses xhr

Answer (score 1):

It's not ideal, but you can right-click on the request, select copy -> "copy as fetch", then paste and execute in the console. Why can't that happen with a single click in the context menu (in 2024)? idk.